# Javascript Equation for displaying popup grid

Tags: javascript, popup, grid, position, equation

I am trying to open all popups from a queue so that they have varying sizes and positions in relation to how many items are in my queue array. When the popups are launched, the idea is that they will completely fill the users screen (using screen.width and screen.height) no matter if 2 popups open or 200. I have figured out the equation for the width of each popup, but havent been able to for height or top and left positions. I believe that the height attribute have something to do with width in relation to screen aspect ratio (screen.width/screen.height) but I may be wrong.

Here is the code, thanks for the help!

```
 var queue = [someUrl, someUrl, someUrl, someUrl];

 function popUp(){ //open popups

    var W=screen.width/Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(queue.length));

    for(i=0; i<queue.length; i++) {
        window.open(queue[i],i,'width='+W+',height='???',toolbar=0,
        menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,left='???'
        ,top='???'');
    }
}
```

`W*i` almost works for `left=`however, it fails to redistribute the popups once one reaches the right side of the screen. Perhaps a conditional statement could be used for `if (W*i>screen.width)`.

Comment: I voted up for the good title language :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking at the related questions on the side I found the answer (more or less) written in another language. Trick is to first calculate the number of rows and columns your grid needs to have (based on the length of your array), then to do a loop inside a loop, where the first loop iterates your rows and the second your columns.

here's the javascript translation of that other answer

```
function popUp(){ 

    // calculate number of rows and columns 
    var cols = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(queue.length));    
    var rows = Math.ceil(queue.length/cols);

    // calculate width and height based on number of cols && rows
    var W = screen.width / cols;
    var H = screen.height / rows;

    var item = 0; //item of the queue array

    for(i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<cols; j++) {

            window.open(queue[item],item,'width='+W+',height='+H+',toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,left='+W*j+',top='+H*i+'');

            item++; //add 1 to item
            if(item >= queue.length) { break } //break out of loop once item reaches length of queue

        }                                            
    }
}
```

this loop would always create a perfect grid, which might not always be what you want, if you've got an odd number of items the last row should be missing a few cells, but this loop-ina-loop would create empty pop ups to finish off the grid, this is why we add that last line to break out of the loop once items >= queue.length (i.e. once you've reached the end of your queue)

**UPDATE**:
here's looping in reverse (little easier to read up here than in the comment)

```
    for(i=rows-1; i>=0; i--) {
        for(j=cols-1; j>=0; j--) {
            //pop up code
        }                                            
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, this is genius! Any idea how to reverse the order in which the windows open? If I do that all of the popups will overlap the window heading (title, url, etc) of the one below it and all will be hidden except the top row.

Comment: try reversing the loop order:     
        for(i=rows-1; i>=0; i--) {
            for(j=cols-1; j>=0; j--) {
                //pop up code
            }                                            
        }